# Set checkbox value in all checkbox of grid

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, checkbox

How to set all checkbox value from column header checkbox, I am having following function on click for column header checkbox having argument column header name & checkbox object.

```
function handleClick(cb, sName) {
  var table= $("#GridName");
  $('td input:checkbox',table).prop('checked',cb.checked);
}
```

`cb` is checkbox instance.
This function working but setting value in all checkbox for all column in grid, how to add filter for grid if `sName` is column name.

Comment: `$('tr[name="sName"] td input:checkbox',table).prop('checked',cb.checked);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group all your check boxes with a data-attributes.

Ex : all the checkboxes in `col1` can have

```
 <input type="checkbox" data-col-name='col1'/>;
```

Ex : all the checkboxes in `col2` can have

```
 <input type="checkbox" data-col-name='col2'/>;
```

In `handleClick`:

```
function handleClick(cb, sName) {
  var table= $("#GridName");
  $("td input[data-col-name='" + sName + "']",table).prop('checked',cb.checked);
}
```